# Visual studio cordova tools - unable to run / debug / deploy to android. adb hangs

Tags: android, adb, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build / deploy and debug by pressing F5 on my Cordova Tools javascript project with a variety of android targets but the apk does not want to deploy.

It appears that the build completes and deploys successfully and the ADB console windows appears but remains blank. No app is deployed to a device or emulator.

Have tried Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and various emulators. All devices have been used as debug targets before

The thing that has changed is that I recently formatted my laptop and moved to Windows 10 Enterprise

I'm using a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

I can debug OK on Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 10

If I try and deploy the APK created from the console with ADB:

> adb install android-debug.apk

I get

> 3715 KB/s (1141677 bytes in 0.300s)
>        pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug-unaligned.apk
>        Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

I haven't tinkered with the APK it is as it was built from VS

I have tried clearing the cache, checking the dependencies (both in Options) and checked for updates.

Any suggestions on how to move forward?

Thanks

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m looking for subject-matter experts like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Turns out the config.xml settings were incorrect. Config.xml > Common > Package name needs to be in reverse domain name notation for android to deploy to the device.

I hadn't noticed this however because I had only been using the Cordova Tools project to compile for Windows 8.1 / 10 devices and in these build configurations the package naming convention is not enforced

This caused the problem:

Package name: mycompany.myappname

This fixed the problem:

Package name: com.mycompany.myappname

Comment: Great! Works also for me! VS 2015 Update 3 with ionic template.

Answer (score 1):

Try in the command line/terminal, navigate to the root of your project folder, and enter "cordova platform remove android.” Then, rebuild the solution again (which will generate platform/android from a clean state)

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for replying. I tried the suggestion you made which resulted in the Android platform been removed and then recreated on subsequent Run on Android Device. Situation remains the same however, a blank ADB window with no App installed on device. FYI i'm running Cordova Tools 6